# animate from the center to the left with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have 3 buttons centered in a container.
When the user click on one of them the button should go to the left top of the container. Other buttons should disapper.

I succeed to do it but I can't make the button to begin animation from the original position, this is because I change the button position to absolute before starting animation.

I think the right approach is to give the buttons absolute position from the begining but I don't know if it is possible (the page should be responsive).

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="inner_body" style="position:relative;margin: auto;text-align: center;width:50%;margin-top: 200px">
        <button class="bc" id="0" style="margin-top: 400px;margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">Botton A</button>
        <button class="bc" id="1" style="margin-top: 400px;margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">Botton B</button>
        <button class="bc" id="2" style="margin-top: 400px;margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">Botton C</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

And Jquery script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.bc', function() {
    $('#' + this.id + '').css({
        position: 'absolute'
    }).animate({
        left: 0,
        marginTop: 0
    }, "slow");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
        if (i != this.id) {
            $('#' + i + '').delay(1200).fadeOut(300);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The `inner_body` has fixed `height`?

Comment: No. The inner body height is dynamic.It will be filled with more text after clicking the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the initial position of element using `'position'` and re-use it before starting animation.

```
var x=$(this).position().left;
var y=$(this).position().top;
$(this).css({'position': 'absolute','top': y+'px','left': x+'px'})
```

Comment: OK it works - first I set it for all 3 buttons and then I activated animation!

Answer (score 0):

I just updated for handling auto height of `#inner_body` (*jsfiddle updated too*)

**HTML**

```
<div id="inner_body">
    <button>Botton A</button>
    <button>Botton B</button>
    <button>Botton C</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#inner_body {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #718bf3;
}

button:nth-child(1) {
    left: 40px;
}

button:nth-child(2) {
    left: 170px;
}

button:nth-child(3) {
    left: 300px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    }, "slow").css('bottom', 'auto');
    $(this).siblings().delay(1200).fadeOut(300);
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/dLgjdcku/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt with css `transition` property
https://jsfiddle.net/abkow4zt/1/

```js
$(document).on('click', '.bc', function () {
  
  $(this).css({'top': $(this).position().top + 'px','left': $(this).position().left + 'px'}); // set origin position
   $(this).addClass('onclick'); // add class with transition to clicked button
 
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('button.bc').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('onclick')) $(this).fadeOut(300); // smoth hide other buttons
      }, 1200); // after 1200ms deylay
    });

});
```

```css
#inner_body {
  position:relative;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

button {
  margin-top: 400px;
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #718bf3;
  transition: transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s, -ms-transform 1s;
}

.onclick {
    position: absolute;
    -ms-transform: translate(-20px, -400px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-20px, -400px);
    transform: translate(-20px, -400px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inner_body">
  <button class="bc" id="0">Botton A</button>
  <button class="bc" id="1">Botton B</button>
  <button class="bc" id="2">Botton C</button>
</div>
```